# How to listen for web notification permission change

Tags: javascript, web, permissions, notifications, listener

According to the [Notification.permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission) spec from MDN, we can check the current user permission for web notification.

However, is there any way to listen for this permission change? Something like this?

```
.on(Notification.permission, 'changed', function(){ }
```

Answer (score 20):

I believe it's a little late for an answer, but... You can use this.

```
var Notification = window.Notification || window.mozNotification || window.webkitNotification;

var was_questioned = false;
if (Notification.permission == 'default') {
    was_questioned = true;
}

Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
    if (was_questioned) {
        console.log("User was asked. New permission is: " + permission);
    }
    if ('permissions' in navigator) {
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'notifications'}).then(function(notificationPerm) {
        notificationPerm.onchange = function() {
            console.log("User decided to change his seettings. New permission: " + notificationPerm.state);
        };
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20):

You just neeed

```
if ('permissions' in navigator) {
  navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'notifications' }).then(function (notificationPerm) {
    notificationPerm.onchange = function () {
      console.log("User decided to change his seettings. New permission: " + notificationPerm.state);
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: upvoted this answer few days ago, everything worked well, but for some reason it doesn't work in FF now, event doesn't fire. nothing in console. chrome is OK.

Comment: upd: doesn't work  on local, but works on production oO

Comment: This approach doesn't work, if user closes native notifications prompt several times in a row, permission is changed by the browser to 'denied', but listener can't handle it

Comment: I think it should be noted that this is using the Permissions API, which is a working draft.

Comment: @teran You probably need an ssl certificate in your local enviroment, since it only works in a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission).

Comment: @teran From Firefox 72 onwards, Notification can only be called in response to a user gesture such as a click event.

Comment: this only works in safari 16+