# How to add a callback to a function in the moment when it is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications, web-push

I would like to add a callback to this function: `Notification.requestPermission()`. The problem is I don't know when exactly it (that function) will be triggered, hence I think I have to bind the browser notification permission box on click or something like that, to achieve that everytime user clicks on `"ALLOW"`, `"BLOCK"` or `"X"(close)` the javascript file finds out what button was clicked on and does something like this:

```
if (result === 'denied')
{
    console.log('Permission wasn\'t granted. Allow a retry.');
    return;
}
if (result === 'default')
{
    console.log('The permission request was dismissed.');
    return;
}
if (result === 'accepted')
{
    console.log('The permission request was accepted.');
    return;
}
```

My problem is I don't know how it can be binded to that browser notification permission box like the one below ↓

[image: browser notification permission box]

I do not want to call the permission prompt i.e. `Notification.requestPermission()` function. I just want to detect when `Permission` was changed and do something with that result.

Comment: You need to understand how to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You can use `Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { ... });`

Comment: The problem is I do not want to call the permission prompt i.e. `Notification.requestPermission()`, I just want to detect when `Permission` was changed and do something with that result.

Comment: Maybe you can try with a combination of [pushsubscriptionchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/onpushsubscriptionchange) and `Notification.permission`

Answer (score 1):

You generally request for permission on page load.
With jquery you can do something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    console.log("This browser does not support desktop notification");
} else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
        if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
            Notification.permission = permission;
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

soo, i'm not entirely sure, if i understand you right, but i don't think you need to bind your stuff to the notification permission box.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission) there are two ways to do this: either use `promises`:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { ... });
```

or the `callback`

```
Notification.requestPermission(callback);
```

I think it's more obvious for the promise how to get the value of the permission, but if you'd use a "normal" callback you could wrap your code into a function and check for the permission parameter:

```
function doStuff(result){
  if (result === 'denied')
   {
     console.log('Permission wasn\'t granted. Allow a retry.');
     return;
    }
  if (result === 'default')
 {
    console.log('The permission request was dismissed.');
    return;
  }
 if (result === 'accepted')
{
   console.log('The permission request was accepted.');
   return;
 }
}
```

and then call:

```
Notification.requestPermission(doStuff(permission));
```

then maybe save the result in a global var ( i don't know what you want to do with it, so yeah)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing and I found this answer here:
[How to listen for web notification permission change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217959/how-to-listen-for-web-notification-permission-change)

I think this is what you are looking for. It is working for me.