# chrome notifications unsubscribe event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

Is it possible to catch unsubscribe event ?

This is the code im using to subscribe the user to the notifications

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
      reg.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true
      }).then(function(sub) {
          add_endpoint_to_db( sub ); // im adding the user deatils to my db
      }).catch(function(e) {
        if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {

        } else {

        }
      });
  });
```

}

In case the user chooses to manually remove the notifications

[image: Notification removal]

I want to catch the action in order to remove his entry from the DB

So is it possible to catch the notifications change event ?

Comment: Hi, I'm also looking to this because to many entries in DB, after manualy subscribing back new entry is created.

Comment: When I go to `chrome://settings/content/notifications` and remove your site’s permission to show notifications from there, I don’t even need to currently have your site itself loaded in my browser at that point ... so I don’t see anyone who _could_ catch that event even if it existed in that situation ...

Comment: @CBroe Hi thank you for reply, but in this case how can I delete the endpoint attached to the user in my DB? because next time user will allow notifications I'm generating a new Endpoint, this makes 2 endpoint for the user (because they are always different).

Comment: May be this can help [How to listen for web notification permission change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217959/how-to-listen-for-web-notification-permission-change?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your looking for the [pushsubscriptionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pushsubscriptionchange) event

```
self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange', function() {
  // remove the entry from DB
});
```

Comment: Hi, what if user don't have internet? It will send request after connecting?

Comment: this has limited browsers support still

Answer (score 1):

Unsubscribe is browser setting that can be done by settings tab and offline mode so you cannot get that information

But Once the user has unsubscribed (i.e. deleted the service worker registration), then on sending the next message you should get a failure message from the FCM API.(if you are using firebase)

So think in this way .... :)