# Trigger update on static browser property change

Tags: reactjs, notifications

I'd like to trigger updates anytime the [`Notification.permission`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission) browser property changes. However, I'm not sure how to do this since `Notification.permission` is static.

The following never prints anything to the console, even if I change my browser's notifications permission:

```
function MyComponent() {
  console.log(Notification.permission);
  return <MoreGreatStuff />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question with [How to listen for web notification permission change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217959/how-to-listen-for-web-notification-permission-change)

Permission state updates can be hooked via `navigator.permissions.query`

The gist:

```
const [permissionState, setPermissionState] = useState()

...

navigator.permissions
  .query({ name: 'notifications' })
  .then(permission => setPermissionState(permission.state)
```

Consumers of `permissionState` will be re-rendered any time it is updated.

This gives you a [`PermissionState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus/state) rather than a [`NotificationPermission`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission), but pish posh it accpmolishes the same thing

Answer (score 0):

There are diffrent option to check for permission

**granted:** The user has explicitly granted permission for the current origin to display system notifications.
**denied:** The user has explicitly denied permission for the current origin to display system notifications.
**default:** The user decision is unknown; in this case the application will act as if permission was denied.

You must check it like that,

```
(Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }
```